# Condition on Inequalities

Tags: inequality

Here $$X=\frac{p}{b+q}+\frac{b^2 p (1+q)+2 b p \left(a p+q^2\right)+q \left(a (-1+p) p+q+p q^2\right)}{\left(b+a p+b q+q^2\right)^2}$$
$$Y=\frac{p^2}{b+a p+b q+q^2}$$

Where $a$, $b$, $p$ and $q$ are all positive such that $p+q<1$.

Does $X<1+Y<2$ hold?

Comment: To me, this falls in the category of "Why bother?". In other words, where did this come from and why is it worth working on?

Comment: This is useful in deriving the condition to bound the zeros of a characteristics polynomial of a square matrix of order 2 inside the unit disk. Here X is trace and Y is determinant of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

For instance, you want $Y<1$, but you can take $p = 0.9$, $q=0.01$, $a=0.001$, and $b=0.01$, and then

$Y \approx 73.$

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%5E2%2F%28b%2Ba*p%2Bb*q%2Bq%5E2%29%20where%20p%3D0.9%2C%20q%3D0.01%2C%20a%3D0.001%2C%20b%3D0.01)